# Three-way diff from clipboard

Tags: diff, meld, kdiff3, p4merge, araxis

I know Kdiff3 can do diff from clipboard but only 2-way.

Is there a tool that allow me copy&paste three text and compare it? Now I have to create three files with the text I copied and compare them. After I delete them.

Can't be online tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 3-way diff using [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) from the clipboard without writing to files by creating a new file comparison, checking the "3-way comparison" option, and choosing "Blank comparison". Then simply paste in the three items.

[image: 3-way clipboard comparison]

Comment: what program? Could not find this screen on kdiff3.

Comment: Answering myself, this is on meld. Thanks!